# How to implements a null-safe Restrictions builder?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm screwing up with the implementation of a method that should take two parameters:

- a [Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html)
- and a list of [Criterion](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion.html)

My code actually is:

```
public static void addNullSafeOrCondition(final Criteria criteria, final Criterion... conditions) {

    final List<Criterion> validCriterion = new ArrayList<Criterion>(conditions.length);

    for (final Criterion condition : conditions) {
        if (condition != null) {
            validCriterion.add(condition);
        }
    }

    if (validCriterion.size() == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (validCriterion.size() == 1) {
            criteria.add(validCriterion.get(0));
        } else {
            //Can't convert list to ... varargs
            criteria.add(Restrictions.or( *** validCriterion *** ));
        }
    }

}
```

I can't find any way to convert an `ArrayList` to  `varargs` but **specially** I'm looking for a better solution, like any existing *HibernateUtils* library or any *Restriction's method*, I didn't know, that create a *null-safe Restrictions*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void addNullSafeOrCondition(final Criteria criteria, final Criterion... conditions) {
    if (conditions == null || conditions.length==0){
        return;
    }

    final List<Criterion> validCriterion = new ArrayList<Criterion>();

    for (final Criterion condition : conditions) {
        if (condition != null) {
            validCriterion.add(condition);
        }
    }
    if (validCriterion.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    //Can't convert list to ... varargs
    criteria.add(Restrictions.or(validCriterion.toArray(new Criterion[ validCriterion.size() ]))); //public static Disjunction or(Criterion... predicates)--work's for one element also
  }
```

criteria.add(Restrictions.or(**validCriterion.toArray(new Criterion[ validCriterion.size() ]))**);

create your own HibernateUtils  and move your method into your onw HibernateUtils

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I appreciated a lot the "null check" in the first line. I'll "accept" your answer for that reason and also cause you ansewered first.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think Hibernate has special utility to check for null. If it needed to do that it would just add the check inside `Restrictions` class or classes that it passes the `Criterion` array.
Given that the Hibernate javadoc does not say anything about `null` in the `public static Disjunction or(Criterion... predicates)` I would assume that it is not expecting `null` in the `predicates` array.

In general libraries dont handle `null` values in the collections unless they explicitly specify how they are going to threat `null`s.

Now back to your code. Maybe you need to avoid passing null Criterion in the first place. Check everywhere `addNullSafeOrCondition` is used and see if you can avoid passing null `Criterion`.

If you can do that then you dont need to define `addNullSafeOrCondition` and can directly use `criteria.add(Restrictions.or(....))` method.

If not then I would change `addNullSafeOrCondition` to be like this:

**Java 8 version:**

```
public static void addNullSafeOrCondition(Criteria criteria, Criterion... conditions) {
    Criterion[] validCriterions = Arrays.stream(conditions).filter( c -> c != null ).toArray( Criterion[]::new );
    if (validCriterions.length == 0) return;
    criteria.add( Restrictions.or(validCriterions) );
}
```

**Java 7 version:**

```
public static void addNullSafeOrCondition(Criteria criteria, Criterion... conditions) {        
    List<Criterion> validCriterions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Criterion c : conditions) if (c != null) validCriterions.add(c);

    if ( validCriterions.isEmpty() ) return;

    criteria.add( Restrictions.or( validCriterions.toArray( new Criterion[ validCriterions.size() ] ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I appreciated the introduction and the "Java 8 version", so I've upvoted your answer. I believe that any user should explain why downvote, upvote or accept an answer, so I've commented both the answers. Sorry, I choose the other answer but it was a difficult choice.